# Get UITextField from UIPickerView when using it as input view

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uipickerview

Is there a possibility to get `UITextField` from `UIPickerView`? I set my `UIPickerView` as `inputView` for text filed. I have few text fields on the screen and I want to simple get current text field that shown picker view.

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
   // something like let textField = pickerView.requestedTextField
}
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: you can get that that textfield by tag , and then make it first responder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have multiple `textField` that show pickerView then create one more instance of `textField` in your viewController like this and use this object inside `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and assign the reference of that `textField` to that tempTextField.

```
var selectedTextField: UITextField = UITextField()

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField!) { 
    self.selectedTextField = textField
}
```

Now in `didSelectRow` method of `PickerView` use this textField o know the current editing field.

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if self.selectedTextField == countryField {
        //Set text for countryField 
    }
    else self.selectedTextField == stateField {
        //Set text for stateField 
    }
}
```

**Note:** For example I have used `countryField` and `stateField` you can use  textField for that you want to set text.

Answer (score 2):

Set same `tag` to your `pickerview` and `textfield` both.

now you can get your tag in `didSelectRow` like,

```
  let myTag = pickerView.tag
```

and then from `myTag` you can get your `textfield` something like,

```
   let myTextField = self.view.viewWithTag(myTag) as! UITextField
```

Comment: This wouldn't work, since the tag would be assigned to the `UIPickerView` too

Comment: whether it'll function correctly or not depends on the order that the subviews are arranged in. From my testing, it returns whichever one was added first (the `UITextField` or `UIPickerView`).

Comment: no this is your illusion. i have used this concept in my many projects.it's works perfect.  type casting is important in this. in objective - c i am doing it like `(UITextField*)[self.view viewWithTag : 12];` and it will return textfield whether other kind of object is there or not!

Comment: Lion thanks for answer. I have not just one textfield, but I have only one picker view, that's why actually need to get textfield. I need to change values in appropriate textfield. Tags will work for sure. But I supposed maybe there is some simple solution. For sure if we tapped on cell we can set tag for textfield and for picker view and then get need textfield. But then I presume it's ok to use smth like currentTextFieldToModify instance and after section appropriate cell, sent new textfield to that instance. so  we even don't need tags then.

Comment: setting tags is standard way ans simplest also.

Comment: yea I agree that there are a lot of possibilities to do it, but I supposed maybe there is backward chance to get text field from a picker view as it has an input view, so I supposed maybe there is some biding between those UI objects. in any case thanks for answer!

Answer (score 2):

As user Lion rightly pointed out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39511289/3769927), you can get the corresponding `UITextField` by giving both the `pickerView` and `textField` a tag. However, the issue with giving them the *same* tag is that `viewWithTag` may return the `UIPickerView` itself, depending on the order of the subviews.

As this is unreliable, a better solution would be to give the `UITextField` the negative of the tag given to the `UIPickerView` (eg. 1 and -1). To get the `UITextView`, you would do something like this in your method, once you have assigned your picker views and text views opposite tags:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    let textField = view.viewWithTag(-pickerView.tag) as! UITextField
    //Use textField
}
```